# Implementing Pull-to-refresh shifts the cells in UITableViewController downwards

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, addsubview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm facing an issue in placement of UITableViewController and pull to refresh simultaneously.

I have implemented pull to refresh and on implementing pull to refresh an API call is made to the server and data is fetched and displayed in the table view list. The issue is that on pull to refresh, the table moves downwards from its actual position.
Below is my code and screenshot.

```
viewDidLoad{

 refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];

}

- (void)handleRefresh:(id)sender
{
    // do your refresh here...
    [self Data];//method to get data from server
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];

}
```

[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A UITableViewController has a built in refresh control. You do not want to add a new one as a subview to the tableview. Just initialize `self.refreshControl`.

```
viewDidLoad {
  self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
  [self.refreshControl setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
  [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(didRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)didRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender {
  [sender endRefreshing];
  [self Data];
}
```

Comment: thanks,i applied your code but now when i pull down there is no indicator view in the table. didRefresh method is not called on pull down.

Comment: Make sure you are not overriding refreshControl in your subclass. self.refreshControl is implemented in UITableViewController so you do not need to declare it in your class.

Comment: This working but didRefresh method calls two times on pull down,which does not solve my problem.

Comment: Make sure nothing else calls the refresh method and that you include [sender endRefreshing]. Put a breakpoint in didRefresh and check sender. Post some code if you still have problems.

Comment: I checked my code is going in this method:  - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float endScrolling = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
    {
        NSLog(@"Scroll End Called");
        
        bottomRefresh=YES;
        
        [self Data];
        
    }
}
where  [self Data]; called again.

Comment: If you call [self Data] in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating it will be called when the scrollView stops scrolling AND in didRefresh. When you pull down to refresh and then release and the tableView bounces up that will call end decelerating. Just take [self Data] out of the scroll view delegate method.

Comment: I'm using this scroll delegate method because there is bottom refresh also in table view.So,I can't remove [self Data] from it.

Comment: That is not the right method to use because it will get called any time the table view stops scrolling, whether it is at the bottom or not. Also it seems like you would want to call a different method that gets the next page of data and adds it to your data source rather than replacing everything. If you want a quick way to implement bottom refresh (infinite scroll) i suggest you checkout this library https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh